# Smarty issue with nested conditional statements

Tags: php, smarty, oxid

I have a small issue regarding smarty and the OXID eShop. After retrieving a bunch of categories, I try to display only the categories within a special range of "sorting number". Everything below 100 should be displayed. But it also displays the items > 100.

Here is my code snippet:

```
[{foreach from=$oxcmp_categories item=ocat key=catkey name=root}]
    [{if $ocat->getIsVisible() }]
        [{if ((int)$ocat->oxcategories__oxsort <100) }]

            [{if $smarty.foreach.root.index % 3 == 0}]
                <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                <div class="mainMenu sub_[{$smarty.foreach.root.index}]">
                    <div class="mm_header">
                        <p class="mm_headline">[{$ocat->oxcategories__oxtitle->value}]</p>
                     </div>
                     <div> 
                    <img src="[{if $ocat->getThumbUrl() != ''}] [{$ocat->getThumbUrl()}] [{else}] [{'http://placehold.it/299x230'}] [{/if}]" alt="">
                    <p class="mm_desc">[{$ocat->oxcategories__oxdesc}]</p>
                </div>
                </div>

            [{else}]
                <div class="mainMenu sub_[{$smarty.foreach.root.index}]">
                    <div class="mm_header">
                    <p class="mm_headline">[{$ocat->oxcategories__oxtitle->value}]</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="[{if $ocat->getThumbUrl() != ''}] [{$ocat->getThumbUrl()}] [{else}] [{'http://placehold.it/299x230'}] [{/if}]" alt="">
                    <p class="mm_desc">[{$ocat->oxcategories__oxdesc}]</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            [{/if}]
        [{/if}]
    [{/if}]
[{/foreach}]
```

Any ideas where the problem could be?

Comment: Why are you using a templating engine to do your logical operations? If you want to only display 100 categories, you should only send 100 categories from the controller/model to the view.

Comment: It may have something to do with your cast to `int` in the second `if-statement`. Maybe that cast is doing something you're not expecting to do, since it's obviously something else if you have to cast it first. You could try looking at the value of `$ocat->oxcategories__oxsort` when you cast it to an `int`. I would, however, advice you to follow skrilled's tip, and only send the data you need to the form.

Answer (score 2):

AS i found you forgot to write value in your call of sortorder.
You just need to value in below line as i added, it should work.

```
[{if ((int)$ocat->oxcategories__oxsort->value <100) }]
```